# What does "Excuse" mean in GoToMeeting?

Tags: gotomeeting

In the videoconferencing tool GoToMeeting, for each attendee I can:

- Mute him
- Make presenter
- **Excuse** him

[image]

QUESTION: What does GoToMeeting mean by "excusing" someone?

Is it the equivalent of "kicking" in IRC? Or "banning", if that blocks the IP? (anyone with the URL to the meeting can connect).

Answer (score 0):

The meaning is not obvious so I just tried, and I can confirm it is a polite word for "kicking".

Pressing that button will effectively (after a confirmation) kick the attendee out of the meeting, they will see this:

[image]

Note how the vocabulary is "You have been **dismissed** from the meeting".

It is not a "ban" though: the ex-attendee can reload the same meeting URL to come back into the meeting.